# how to to check if jQuery is loaded from C# code, if jQuery is added in plain HTML?

Tags: c#, jquery, sharepoint, user-interface

'm developing a WEB_PART and I'd like to know if there some way to find out if exists any JQUERY LIB inside the master page project where the web part is going to be inserted.
I'd like to do something like this:

```
if (jQuery) {  
 // jQuery is loaded  
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(typeof(WebpartSlideShow), "jQuery",                        "/_layouts/Jquery-Cycle/jquery-1.5.1.min.js");
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(typeof(WebpartSlideShow), "jQueryCycle", "/_layouts/Jquery-Cycle/jquery.cycle.all.min.js");
               // break;
   } else {
  // jQuery is not loaded
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(typeof(WebpartSlideShow), "jQueryCycle", "/_layouts/Jquery-Cycle/jquery.cycle.all.min.js");

  }
```

but it does't work if jQuery is added in plain HTML but only if jQuery was added through                         `Page.ClientScript`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can check if jquery is included in the target page from c#. You can only check that from the component at runtime using js.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could do this I can imagine is to set a cookie with jQuery, then somehow check on the server-side for the existence of this cookie.

I'm not a C# developer so can't help with the exact syntax, but the principle should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try register your own JavaScript code, which should check if jQuery is already loaded and if not load it. The cross-browser example is below.

```
function initScript(url, callback) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    done = false;

    // Attach handlers for all browsers
    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
            done = true;
            callback();
        };
    };

    head.appendChild(script);
};


function initJQuery(callback) {
    //if the jQuery object isn't available
    if (typeof (jQuery) == 'undefined') {
        initScript("/_layouts/YourWebPart/jquery-1.7.1.min.js", function() { callback(); });
    } else {
        callback();
    }   
}

initJQuery(function () {
    alert('loaded');    
});
```